# Python - taking a variable and inserting into a mysqlDB

Tags: python, string

This is probably simpler than I've made it.

basically I'm writing my second python script here.  I want to open a mysql connection, process a for loop, and then insert the x int into a database.

I have everything working, expect, I'm unsure of how to insert the xstring instead of literal xstring.  In C# it would be `'" + xstring +"'` but i'm not sure how to do this in Python.

Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys

try:
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'PythonTest');
with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        for x in range(0, 3):
                xstring = str(x)

                    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Testing(KeyColumn,KeyValue) VALUES('Jack London','"xstring"')

except _mysql.Error, e:

print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
sys.exit(1)

finally:

if con:
    con.close()
```

Comment: Did you try what worked with C#? Besides, since you are *formatting* you may be interested by the [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method

Comment: well yeah because you would do string xstring = x.ToString() and then you would place it in the value, which is simple enough

Comment: What I meant is that writing `"..." + xstring + "  "` **does** creating the concatenation of the strings, exactly as in C#.

Comment: @Bakuriu LOL!!! wow talk about easy...

Comment: @Bakuriu now... how do i get input html controls to python in order to insert what a user puts inside of the input!

Comment: You can also do this `cur.execute("INSERT INTO Testing(KeyColumn,KeyValue) VALUES('Jack London',?)", (xtring,))` is better to avoid SQL injection :), particularly if you want to insert user values

Answer (score 0):

Python's [DB API specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) specifies it like this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Testing(KeyColumn,KeyValue) VALUES('Jack London', %s), (x,))
```

Warning: Never, ever use raw string formatting on DB queries, that would allow little B[obby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) to inject nasty things into your DB. Instead use library methods for parameterizing SQL queries.

Comment: Actually the DB API specifies different type of styles for the parameters of a query. See [`paramstyle`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle).

Comment: @Bakuriu you're correct, this isnt parameterized, this is simply an insert havinh python cast the string

Comment: But even if you trust the input, the little possible speed gain means nothing in Python. I think its best to stick to best practices. I mean, why not?